# Unsuccessfully extracting InnerText from child nodes of XML document (C#)

Tags: c#, xml

The XML I'm working with is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><entry_list version="1.0"><entry 
id="commode"><ew>commode</ew><subj>HH-2#CL-1#FU-2a,b,c#BD-2d</subj><art>
<artref id="commode" /><capt>commode 1</capt><dim>54,18</dim></art>
<hw>com*mode</hw><sound><wav>commod01.wav</wav><wpr>ku-!mOd</wpr></sound>
<pr>kə-ˈmōd</pr><fl>noun</fl><et>French, from <it>commode,</it> adjective, 
suitable, convenient, from Latin <it>commodus,</it> from <it>com-</it> + 
<it>modus</it> measure <ma>mete</ma></et><def><date>circa 1688</date>
<sn>1</sn><dt>:a woman's ornate cap popular in the late 17th and early 18th 
centuries</dt><sn>2 a</sn><dt>:a low chest of drawers</dt><sn>b</sn><dt>:a 
movable washstand with a cupboard underneath</dt><sn>c</sn><dt>:a boxlike 
structure holding a chamber pot under an open seat</dt><sd>also</sd><dt>:
<sx>chamber pot</sx></dt><sn>d</sn><dt>:<sx>toilet <sxn>3b</sxn></sx></dt>
</def><art><bmp>commode.bmp</bmp><cap>commode 
1</cap></art></entry></entry_list>
```

The code I'm using, which I cobbled together from various related questions:

```
System.Xml.XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("dt");
List<string> defs = new List<string>();

for (int count = 0; count < elemList.Count; count++)
{
    string contents = string.Empty;
    foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode child in elemList[count])
    {

        if (child.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            contents += child.InnerText;
        }
    }
    defs.Insert(count, contents);
}
```

The resulting List of "defs" is empty for any number of reasons, all of which are unknown to me.

Comment: Your XML doesn't seem to be correct to begin with. There's no root node.

Comment: That's correct, Sach - I trimmed off the top portion for brevity.

Comment: Don't sacrifice accuracy for brevity. I can't replicate the problem if so. Please post the correct XML, this doesn't look right.

Comment: Sorry, I was having trouble with the formatting of the XML. (Is there a quicker way than indenting each separate line 4 spaces?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is using LINQ. Pass "dt" for the `elementName` parameter.

```
static List<string> GetInnerText(XDocument xDoc, string elementName)
{
    var children = from node in xDoc.Descendants(elementName).DescendantNodes()
                   where node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text
                   select ((XText)node).Value;
    return children.ToList();
}
```

I'm not sure if above is exactly what you want, so here's an alternative solution.

```
static List<string> GetInnerText(XmlDocument xDoc, string elementName)
{
    List<string> innerText = new List<string>();
    var children = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName(elementName);
    foreach (XmlNode child in children)
        innerText.Add(child.InnerText);
    return innerText;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, Sach. I'm going to give this a go shortly.

Comment: Looking at your original attempted code above I'm not sure if I understand correctly exactly what you want. So I updated my answer with a second method too, see which one solves your problem.

Comment: Ultimately I'd like a collection of strings - one for each "dt" element that has the inner tags stripped away, if that makes more sense.

Comment: What would be your expected output for this XML: <root>
 <dt>DTData1</dt>
 <sx>
  <dt>
   <sx>SXData1</sx>
   <sx>SXData2</sx>
   <dt>DTData2</dt>
  </dt>
  <dt>DTData3</dt>
 </sx>
</root>

Comment: The desired result would be a collection of 3 strings: "DTData1" , "DTData2", "DTData3" although it appears there's an extra <dt> tag in the above example.

Comment: I added that extra tag specifically to show you there are situations that aren't straightforward. So tell me if I'm wrong; your requirement is to get the Text of 'leaf' `<dt>` nodes?

Comment: I see what you mean. Given the snippet from the XML I'm using <dt>:<sx>toilet <sxn>3b</sxn></sx></dt> , I'm looking for the string ": toilet 3b"

Comment: What if your string is like `<dt>
 :
 <sx>
  toilet
  <sxn>3b</sxn>
  <dt>DTDATA</dt>
 </sx>
</dt>` ?
Is then your expected output one string containing `:toilet 3bDTDATA` or is it two strings one containing `:toilet 3b` and the other `DTDATA`?

Comment: I've yet to encounter any overlapping <dt> tags, but in that event I could just cram it all into one string.

Comment: If you don't have overlapping <dt> tags then it's pretty simple. My second example should work.

Comment: Indeed, that second one seems to do the trick. I Appreciate the help/patience.

Answer (score 0):

`elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("dt");` returns an XmlNodeList. You can directly iterate this.

change this `System.Xml.XmlNode child in elemList[count]` to `System.Xml.XmlNode child in elemList` and look at the value of `child` in debugger.